# SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG after VM migration

Tags: ssl-certificate, hyper-v, certbot

I have a strange issue whereby I am using certbot on a VM which is working fine, no issues.

I tried to migrate the VM onto another (physical) host as part of a server migration piece of work and when I restarted the VM on the new host, I was getting `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`. Going back to the old host, all works OK, which is confusing as the new host has an exact replicated version of the VM, so they should be (within 5 minutes) identical VM’s…

The VM’s were migrated via the Hyper-V replication method. Interestingly I had two nearly identical VM’s and one worked, the other one didn’t and gave the above error.

I've tried twice now to fire up the replicated VM, which should be an identical replica, but I keep on getting that error. The domain is the same, IP address is the same, the file structure would be the same, the only thing that would change would be the MAC address (and one physical host runs 2012R2 and the other runs 2016), but I cannot see how this would cause the issue, plus it worked for another, nearly identical VM.

Has anyone experienced this or any ideas what I can do to resolve?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting the `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` message from? Did you look at the log files of your `certbot`? Does your target Hyper-V host allow proper Internet connection for its guests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot answer why, but during an outage I used the opportunity to move the VM back over again and when the system came back up again, it all worked on the new host.

I can only assume that there was a conflict (somewhere) that I cannot explain nor understand, that was causing this problem and needed a little more time to 'settle down' than I was giving it.

No idea, but ultimately I just needed to wait a bit more...